# How to add a single item to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, insert

Please excuse my lack of python knowledge, i am still learning :)

I have been scouring the web to try and find an answer for this. I can find information on inserting all values into the indexed position, but cannot find anything on inserting **singular items at a specific point**. I want to just add a **single item** inside a **2D array** using `numpy.insert`

so far, i have this code:

```
import numpy as np

# Initialise 2D Array
a = np.array([[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(5)])

a = np.insert(a, 0, 1, axis=1)

print(a)
```

The output i am getting is:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The output i am *trying* to achieve is:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I know this is probably quite a simple solution for more adept programmers. If this question has already been answered in  different thread, feel free to reply with the link. :)

Comment: `insert` makes a larger array.  In your example you start with (5,10) shape, and get back a (5,11).  Is that what you really want?  Or do you want a (5,10) with the [0,0] element being 1?   `np.zeros((5,10), int)` is direct `numpy` way of creating `a`.  If you found the `np.insert` docs confusing, you should experiment with the examples.

Comment: `np.insert` only adds a new row or column to an array.  It does not add a single element (and fill in the rest of that column and/or row).   Assigning a new value to an existing element of an array is quite a different action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and reach the element you want by indexing on the two dimensions e.g.

```
import numpy as np

# Initialise 2D Array
a = np.array([[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(5)])

a[0,0] = 1
a
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: That is a good point, I agree with your question on the original post - inserting a new value wouldn't achieve the desired output, like inserting 1 into [0,0,0] to achieve [1,0,0,0]

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem! Turns out, i had no idea you could access these items through the method mentioned in your answer (a[0,0]).. You have made my day :)